# Better methods to compare corresponding values in multiple arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist, compare

I have an ArraysList containing `M` lists which are sorted. Each list in the Arraylist has the same size `N`. Now I want to compare the first `(N-1)`  corresponding values in each list with others and I want to find those list with the same first`(N-1)` values. Intuitively, it can be done by two for-loops, but the complexity could be as high as `M*N*N`. I was wondering whether there are some better algorithms to do this. By the way, `M` could may be a very large number while `N` tends to be a smaller one.

Sorry, I might not be clear. I want the final output is pairs of list which have the same first `(N-1)` values.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `N*M` rather than `M*(N^2)`?

Comment: What types of values are in the lists that you're comparing?

Comment: Suppose all the values are int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a good hashing algorithm to calculate a hash code of the `N-1` items in each row. Organize rows by their hash code, and do a full compare only when the hash codes match.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list of lists.

Sorting them is `O(N M LOG M)` (assuming that a comparison is `O(N)`).

If you do this in a radix sort approach, it should actually be more on the lines of `O(N * M)` or even `O(M LOG M)`  total (assuming the lists are not identical).

Then lists with the same prefix must be subsequent in this list.

Assuming that you are trying to reimplement APRIORI: yes, *do* keep a sorted list of candidate itemsets. This is exactly what Apriori-Gen needs for building the next round candidates. Keeping them organized as a sorted tree is quite neat, as this is also fast when scanning the database for counting itemsets.